# How to scan barcode in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, barcode-scanner

i am having trouble with the barcode scanner. someone please help

i don't know if this is the correct way but this is the code i gave for button.

```
Row(
        children:
        [const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10)),
          const Text('Barcode',style:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.deepOrange),
          ),
      const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100)),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.qr_code),
            onPressed: () {
              scanBarcode();
            },
          ),
          const Text('Scan Code',style:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: It's not so complicated to create a button. We're using the mobile_scanner package. It's well maintained, and easy to use. 
Follow this link: https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal type: "flutter pub add flutter_barcode_scanner" and hit enter.

Then add those codes outside the build method:

```
  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
String barcodeScanRes;

// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
      '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
  print(barcodeScanRes);
} on PlatformException {
  barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
}

// If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
// message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
// setState to update our non-existent appearance.
if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {
  _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
});}
```

Then implement any button to start the scanner:

```
IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.qr_code_2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                onPressed: () => scanBarcodeNormal(),
              ),
```

You are ready to go.